# How to get text from dynamically created textboxes so as to store in database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where n number of text boxes are created according the value n from  a drop down list. My question is about accessing the values from the textboxes into string variables so that I can store them in database.
Following is the code for creating textboxes

```
 protected void ddlNumOfVolunteers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {


        // Get the number of labels to create.
        int numlabels = System.Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumOfVolunteers.SelectedItem.Text);
        for (int i = 1; i <= numlabels; i++)
        {
            Label myLabel = new Label();
            TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
            // Set the label's Text and ID properties.
            myLabel.ID = "LabelVol" + i.ToString();
            myLabel.Text = "Volunteer " + i.ToString();
            txtbox.ID = "TxtBoxVol" + i.ToString();
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(myLabel);
            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(txtbox);
            // Add a spacer in the form of an HTML <br /> element.
            PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        } 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Then when I click on the save button beneath, I want to access all the values in the dynamically created textboxes and store into a datastructure such as array.

I used the following code and I know it won't work as TxtBoxVol1 won't be available in this block. so how can I store the values in an array when in ddlNumOfVolunteers_SelectedIndexChanged function itself.

```
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.FindControl("PlaceHolder2").FindControl("TxtBoxVol1");
string vol1name = tb.Text;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use an array or a List<T> to store the instances, job done, now you just have to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

There are oodles of ways to do this.

However, you could just store them in an `array` of `List<T>` or even a `Dictionary`

```
Dictionary<string,Textbox> myControls = new Dictionary<string,Textbox>();

...

TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
txtbox.Id = "TxtBoxVol" + i.ToString();
myControls.Add(txtbox.Id,txtbox)

...

var myValue = myControls["TxtBoxVol1"].Text 


// when you are finished 
myControls.Clear();
```